# Best way to view a menu screen from server after successful login?

Tags: java, javascript, android, forms, android-webview

So i am at the point where i can verify if a username/password is correct or not, now i need to show the user a menu screen if the log in is successful. When i log in successfully i get a JavaScript/HTML response from the server. Should i make a webview and run the script on that to get the menu screen? Is that the only way to do it? If not, let me know the options i have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What kind of a menu are you going to show? A menu can be implemented in various ways. I usually use AlertDialog for simple menus. You could create an Activity for a menu if you like.

I could suggest using an AsyncHttpClient. Override the onSuccess method, if the log in response is affirmative on the server side, show your menu ( like an AlertDialog as a menu, or open an Activity etc.)